# Not switching accounts in same project on button click

Tags: java, android

This is an app about layout
first the screen will be in portrait layout on clciking button it will be changed to landscape layout.so here on clicking button it is not going to next activity though no compilation errors are found

**activity_main.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.vamshivikas.orientation.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:text="@string/this_is_potrait_layout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.48"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/go_to_next_activity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/this_is_landscape_layout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**activityManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vamshivikas.orientation">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.vamshivikas.orientation.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

           <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
               android:screenOrientation="landscape">

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**mainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.vamshivikas.orientation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
public void onClcik(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**secondActivity.java**

```
package com.example.vamshivikas.orientation;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
}
```

Comment: Use debugger to see what is a problem. Don't post entire app code, nobody is going to waste multiple hours just to setup the project and to find where the problem in your entire code is.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you have no onClick-Attribute in your Button-Element in activity_main.xml.
Give your Button an onClick-Attribute like this

```
<Button
android:onClick="onButtonNextActivityClick"
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="47dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:text="@string/go_to_next_activity"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

and then create a public void method in MainActivity.java with the same name and handle your stuff in there. Like this:

```
public void onButtonNextActivityClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And Consider using MrFishermans solution too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you in a good way, you want to go the another Activity when you click on Button? You also want to switch View to Landscape?

You can do: (in onClick() function)

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);`

And then in your second activity, in onCreate() function call:

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`